# that is no updated about modification of beautiful-jekyll

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, themes, jekyll

i got a fork about https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll
and i checked url is working...
but when i modify _config and md files
but that is no updated.
actually i'm not good at ruby. but i don't understand why no update.
is there anyone to help me ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7ONL.png)

---

### layout: page
title: changing
subtitle: Why you'd want to go on a date with me

Answer (score 0):

Do you have experience with Jekyll?

The first thing I would check is that your server is running and without any changes you can view the website by visiting https://localhost:4000

Is the server is running, when you save a file you should see it say that it is rebuilding.

From your screenshot it looks like you're maybe editing the files directly in Github. Github is a bit of a blackbox when it comes to running Jekyll, I would advise getting it running locally first.